# Travelling from uk to mexico via canada

Tags: uk, canada, mexico, stopovers, eta

Planning to go to mexico with stopovers in canada.

Canadian government websites says that travelling to Canada after 15/03/16 requires application of an eTA (electronic travel authorisation). It doesn't state any rules on transiting, so I would assume that I would have to apply for this before I travel. Could anyone shed any more light on this, and confirm whether i need to apply or not?

Comment: Have you checked the [offical website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/transit.asp)? It is quite clear, and the answer depends on your citizenship, which you have not specified.